# Word Choice in a Sentence

Tags: word-choice

Which is clearer:
The customer made a tub selection and it is expected to arrive next week.
or
The customer made a tub selection that is expected to arrive next week.

Comment: It makes no difference.  But why do you have to write “made a tub selection” and not just “selected a tub”?  After all, what will arrive is not a selection but  tub!

Answer (score 0):

The first phrase could work but, personally, I would probably turn it into two sentences. 
e.g *The customer made a tub selection and it is expected to arrive next week*. to *The customer made a tub selection. It is expected to arrive next week*. 
The second phrase would definitely need to be punctuated or slightly rephrased e.g. *The customer made a tub selection that is expected to arrive next week.* to *The customer selected a tub, that is expected to arrive next week.*
I think that it should be "made a selection" (no object described) or "selected a ..." (specific object). You could take out *selection* entirely and use *chose* instead e.g. *The customer chose a tub, that is expected to arrive next week.* This would also give a more positive action to the choice, as the past tense of choose - the Oxford dictionary definition being "*Pick out (someone or something) as being the best or most appropriate of two or more alternatives."*

Answer (score 0):

"The customer selected a tub, which is expected to arrive next week." Then it's very clear that the "which" is referring to the "tub". I also like "which" better than "that" here because "expected to arrive next week" feels to me like a non-restrictive, subordinate clause.